# Nemo keyboard shortcuts overwritten

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcuts, nemo

I read a lot about how you can make Nemo your standard file browser in Ubuntu 14.04. I managed to install it and most of the standard actions are performed by Nemo and no longer by nautilus - as it should be. But there is one thing I cannot manage to do:

I cannot make Nemo to accept my keyboard shortcuts, which I declared in `~/.gnome2/accels/nemo`. It seems like this file gets overwritten when I restart Nemo. What I want to achieve is that I can open a Terminal in the currently openend directory. What I tried was editing the line `; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInTerminal" "<Primary><Alt>z")` in the file `~/.gnome2/accels/nemo`. However, any changes are lost after the next start of nemo.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I am stupid. If you remove the `;` in front of the line  `; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInTerminal" "<Primary><Alt>z")` everything works. Sorry for the foolish question.

Comment: If you found solution please post your own answer for helping to other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer by myself:

If you remove the `;` in front of the line  `; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInTerminal" "<Primary><Alt>z")` everything works. Sorry for the foolish question.